# Pass values from Numeric control into corresponding cells in DataGridView control with a button

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to move the values from each of four Numeric Up/Down controls into the DataGridView columns/rows with a button.  For instance, the operator sets the values in the up/down numeric controls and then clicks the button.  The program should then add a new row to the DataGridView and pass whatever values that are in the Numeric Up/Down controls into the new cells of the new row.  As of now, I have the adding new rows part of it working as well as the delete button working (delete last row of the DataGridView).  Now, how to pass the Numeric control values into the cell of the new row of the DataGridView with the button?  Each new row created of the DatGridView has four cells to correspond to the four Numeric up/down controls.  Thank you.

```
Private Sub addStep_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addStep_btn.Click
    LftMtr_Data_Grid.ColumnCount = 4
    LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount = LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount + 1
    LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(0).HeaderText = "  Spindle Speed              (rpm)"
    LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(1).HeaderText = "     Accel Rate         (rpm/S)"
    LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(2).HeaderText = "     Decel Rate         (rpm/S)"
    LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(3).HeaderText = "        Time (S)"
    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns
        c.Width = 120
    Next

    Dim rowNumber As Integer = 1
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For
        row.HeaderCell.Value = "Step " & rowNumber
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next

    LftMtr_Data_Grid.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)
    rowCount1 = LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount
    txtBox1.Text = rowCount1
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` set to?  Are you using a `DataTable` object to hold the values or something else?

Comment: There is not a DataSource linked to the DataGridView.  No, I am not using a DataTable object to hold the values.  Would that be a better way to do it?  As of now, I have the user interface set up where the program starts with an empty DataGridView.  The user uses the numeric up down controls at the top of the form and then clicks a button, and then that adds a new row and populates each cell of the row with the values from the Up/Down numeric controls.  That part works good in my program.  But now I also need to add those values to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.  Note that you don't need to setup the column headers everytime, just once in the Load() event would do!

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.ColumnCount = 4
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(0).HeaderText = "  Spindle Speed              (rpm)"
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(1).HeaderText = "     Accel Rate         (rpm/S)"
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(2).HeaderText = "     Decel Rate         (rpm/S)"
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns(3).HeaderText = "        Time (S)"
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Columns
            c.Width = 120
        Next
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)
    End Sub

    Private Sub addStep_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addStep_btn.Click
        Dim values() As Object = {NumericUpDown1.Value, NumericUpDown2.Value, NumericUpDown3.Value, NumericUpDown4.Value}
        Dim index As Integer = LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.Add(values)
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(index).HeaderCell.Value = "Step " & (index + 1)
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)
    End Sub

    Private Sub delStep_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles delStep_btn.Click
        If LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.RemoveAt(LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.Count - 1)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.  Here is what I came up with:

```
Dim rowNumber As Integer = 1
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For
        row.HeaderCell.Value = "Step " & rowNumber
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentCell = LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount - 1).Cells(0)
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = LftMtr_Speed_Incr.Value
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = LftMtr_Accel_Incr.Value
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = LftMtr_Decel_Incr.Value
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = test_Time_Incr1.Value
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
    Next
```

This application works with an empty or partially filled dataGridView.  When the user clicks the button, the code creates a new row in the dataGridView, makes the new row the selected row, and then finally populates each of the cells in the new row with the values that are in the four Numeric Up/down controls (could be a text box too depending on your application).  This is code copied directly from my specific application.  Yours may differ slightly with variable names, label text, etc.